# Почему фрагменты в android studio не на полный лэйаут?

Tags: android, android-studio

у меня возникла проблема. Делал код по примеру и обнаружил, что фрагменты, которые используются там не на полный экран, какие причины могут повлиять на это, я в этом новичок, поэтому немного сложно пока понять из-за чего это может возникать.
код MainActivity:

```
package com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //add this line to display menu1 when the activity is loaded
        displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_menu1);
    }

    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

        //creating fragment object
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;

        //initializing the fragment object which is selected
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_menu1:
                fragment = new Menu1();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu2:
                fragment = new Menu2();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu3:
                fragment = new Menu3();
                break;
        }

        //replacing the fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        //make this method blank
        return true;
    }
}
```

Код Menu1:

```
package com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Canvas;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.Paint;
        import android.graphics.Rect;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 18/09/16.
 */


public class Menu1 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments

// inflate mainXML

// find container

        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        container.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,250,222,165));
        container.addView(new DrawView(container.getContext()));
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_1, container, false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Menu 1");
    }

    class DrawView extends View {

        Paint p;
        Rect rect;

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p = new Paint();
            rect = new Rect();
        }
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // заливка канвы цветом

            // настройка кисти
            // красный цвет
            p.setColor(Color.argb(255,253,181,91));
            // толщина линии = 10
            p.setStrokeWidth(2);

            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), 56, p);

            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            rect.offset(150, 0);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, p);

            // рисуем прямоугольник
            // левая верхняя точка (200,150), нижняя правая (400,200)
            canvas.drawRect(8, 64, canvas.getWidth()-8, 64 + 320, p);

        }
    }
}
```

[image: скриншот приложения]

---

Я нашел решение, проблема была в константах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут дело в разметке, скорее всего либо layout_margin либо layout _padding контейнера или фрагмента, прикрепи xml фрагмента и контейнера, скажу точнее